# HTTP Endpoint for SNS Notifications in Asp.Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I trying to get SNS Notifications using Http endpoint on ASP.NET Core 6.0.

What I have done so far is

Using ASP.NET MVC application I was successfully able to receive the notifications using the below method in controller.

```
public class SNSController: Controller
{ 
[HttpPost]
public String SNSSubscriptionPost(String id = "")
{
   // recieved notification
   Stream req = Request.InputStream;
   req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
   String json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
   // implemented as par requirement
}
}
```

Then requirements changed I done it in ASP.Net Web API, by using the below code I was able to receive the notifications successfully.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/SNSAPI")]
public class SNSController: ApiController
{ 
[HttpPost, Route["SNSSubscription"]]
public String SNSSubscriptionPost(String id = "")
{
   // recieved notification
   String json = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
   // implemented as par requirement
}
}
```

Now, I am trying to do this in ASP.NET Core Web API by using the below code but my I am not receiving any notifications.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class SNSController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string SNSNotification(string id = "")
    {
        //not receving anyting
    }
}
```

I have also tried using [FromQuery], [FromRoute] attributes but no success.

Comment: How are you invoking this API route? Does it hit your endpoint? Or are you getting any errors? Please share the above information.

Comment: The api will be called from the AWS SNS console. I am invoking this using the AWS SNS console. It was hitting before but when I moved to ASP.NET Core Web API it's not getting hit.